# How to create highlight area under curve in high chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, highcharts, highlight

I create a high chart using angular 4 and I want to highlight a particular portion of Highchart.
Ex Image :https://www.screencast.com/t/MHxo59j2dM

As per above image if data point value goes below to some limit (like 0) then highlight with "**Red**" color and if it goes below 8 then highlight with **Yellow**

I'm not sure whether its possible with Highchart or not but if someone had created this kind of features then please let me know.

Highchart provides Area Chart option - https://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-negative  but my chart is normal and I don't want to highlight all series point.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such functionality in Highcharts, but you can mimic it by using **polygon** series and plot lines:

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {

    plotOptions: {
    polygon: {
        showInLegend: false
    }
  },

    yAxis: {
    tickInterval: 1,
    plotLines: [{
        value: 4,
      color: 'orange',
      width: 2
    }, {
        value: 3,
      color: 'red',
      width: 2
    }]
  },

  series: [{
    data: [6, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7]
  }, {
    type: 'polygon',
    data: [[1,4], [2, 4], [2,3]],
    color: 'orange'
  }, {
    type: 'polygon',
    data: [[5,4], [6, 4], [5,3]],
    color: 'orange'
  }, {
    type: 'polygon',
    data: [[2,3], [5, 3], [4,2], [3,1], [2,3]],
    color: 'red'
  }]
});
```

**Live working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/fbomb7cf/

It will require some programming to make the process of creating these areas automatic (in my fiddle everything is hard-coded).

To achieve similar styling you can try **patter fill** Highcharts plugin: https://www.highcharts.com/blog/extension/pattern-fill/

---

**API references:**

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.polygon
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.plotLines